# Cannot remove console.log statements from a .js file using Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am new to Node.js and I am trying to remove console.log statements from a js file using Gulp. I successfully installed the Gulp modules but when I run the runner.js script nothing happens.

I have my js file located inside a subfolder called 'local_submission'.

See a picture of the structure:

[Folder structure and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTmJj.png)

Not really sure if I am missing anything else.

I basically want to access the index.js file and remove the console log statements.

Thanks for your help.

This is the code I am running :

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulp_remove_logging = require("gulp-remove-logging");

gulp.task("remove_logging", function () {
    return gulp.src("./local_submission/index.js")
        .pipe(gulp_remove_logging())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./local_submission"));
});
```

I thought it would automatically locate the file and replace the console log statements with an empty string.

How would you call the above task from a node js script ?
I saw that gulp.start() is not longer supported.

Comment: 1. include source inline here and not linked on a site 2. gulp is a task runner, so you need to show us what code you are trying to use to "remove console.log statements".

Comment: Also, `gulp TASKNAME --gulpfile runner.js` https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli

Comment: I would be wary of a tool that's supposed to do what this is advertised to do.  Will it remove `window['con' + 'sole']['lo' + 'g']`?  How about `((o,f,g=a=>a.map((n,i)=>String.fromCharCode(n+o[(i%2&&'b'||'a')])).join(''),c= g([0,1,11,5,12,-2,2]),l=g([9,1,4]))=>(...m)=>f[c][l](...m))(o={a:99,b:110,f:()=>this},o.f.call())`, which should do the same thing.